# How to clear pending open balances of Journals in Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I was manually reconciling old invoice balances in odoo 8. Now there are few  journal entries that show journals having opening balance like the one in the image[image: Journal Open balance]

Whenever i try to register a payment for an invoices, the payment amount allocates it to these journals open balance.

Comment: That question has nothing to do with programming. You should ask it on the official [Odoo forums](https://odoo.com/forum/help-1).

Comment: Sorry, had not known that.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to ask this question in Odoo forums.